# Phpunit showing difft version when run

Tags: phpunit, command-line-interface

when I run `/usr/bin/phpunit testfile.php`, the first line it outputs says `PHPUnit 4.7.7`. However, when I run `/usr/bin/phpunit --version`, it outputs `PHPUnit 4.5.0`. Why is phpunit giving me different versions? which one is correct? How do I find out what's going on here?

Comment: I've got no idea, but I list phpunit in composer.json's require-dev section, rather than installing it globally.

Comment: @AlisterBulman Mine comes in through composer as a requirement of another tool, but I also have it installed globally, and they are different versions. But, why (and how) would phpunit use a different binary for tests than for --version?